# API Gateway Proxy Integration. Return response of second lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

The premise is pretty simple.

The usual application flow is as follows:

1. API Gateway receives a request.
2. API Gateway triggers Lambda Function with parameters.
3. Lambda Function runs the logic.
4. The Lambda Function's response is automatically forwarded to API Gateway as the response to step 1 (Response to the Received API Request).

Here's the issue I'm having. I need to run two functions before returning the response to the received API request. I need the return statement from the second function in step 4 to be the response sent back
to the client.

Now there are more examples where this is necessary. In the future, we might need to run a few services (such as lambda > Lambda > PostgreSQL > API Response) before responding to the request.

Is there a way to receive a request from a client, then run a host of tasks, assemble the necessary data, then use this data as a response in the original API request? So far step-functions seemed a likely solution but I don't know if it can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until recently this would've been a pain with Step Functions but around re:invent time last year they announced the ability to orchestrate synchronous express workflows: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-synchronous-express-workflows-for-aws-step-functions/

IMO, this would be the best / easiest way to implement what you're looking for.

Comment: That's very enlightening, thank you. This answers my question